# Need to find string using bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, python-re

We have below string column and having below data

[image]

and I want to find Null count present in string columns means `how many times null value('') present in front of id column present in select statement` 
using big query.

Don't use string position.

Expected output:

```
count of null ('')id =3
1st row,2nd row and 5th row
```

Comment: What is the purpose of all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  FORMAT(
    "count of null ('')id = %d. List of id is: %s", 
    COUNT(*),  
    STRING_AGG(CAST(ID AS STRING))
  ) AS output
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(String, r"(?i)''\s+(?:as|)\s+(?:id|\[id\])")
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - the output is

```
Row output   
1   count of null ('')id = 3. List of id is: 1,2,5
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to unify all strings to something you can query with like = "%''asid%" or regex
First replace all spaces with ''
replace "[", "]" with ''.
Make the use of " or ' consistent.

Then query with like.

For example:

```
select 1 from (select replace(replace(replace(replace('select "" as do, "" as [id] form table1',' ',''),'[',''),']',''),'"',"'") as tt)
where tt like ("%''asid%")
```

Its not a "smart" idea but its simple.

A better idea will be to save the query columns in a repeat column '"" as id' and the table in another column.

You don't need to save 'select' and 'from' this way you can query easily and also assemble a query from the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of appearances of `''` in the `string` column.

If so, you can use `regexp_extract_all()`:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from unnest(regexp_extract_all(t.string, "''")) u
       ) as empty_string_count
from t;
```